# How to start a project using a Watcom compiler?

Tags: fortran, fortran77, watcom

I need to evaluate a Fortran 77 code I wrote using a WATCOM compiler. Long story short, I have no other option for a compiler. It must be this one.

As of now, for this project, I have to read .dat files  and print what it is read in a desired format.

On setting up a new project, Watcom makes a distinction between "targets" and "sources" but I have no idea what this means.

So far, I created a new project and loaded my code as a "source", but I don't know if this is right. I haven't figured out how to load the .dat file, or if I need to load them at all, given that perhaps Watcom may access it without bringing it to its interface.

For the record, I have read this manual but it was of little help. (ftp://ftp.openwatcom.org/pub/manuals/1.5/f_readme.pdf)

I'm still a beginner at coding and any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Sources are your Fortran source code files, targets are the results of the compilation. I highly recommend to abandon any projects and IDE and just use your compiler on the command line.

Comment: Hi, Vladimir. Thanks for your input. Why do you say so, though?

Comment: Experience of teaching Fortran to beginners.